# How can I find all the links inside a specific div via Puppeteer-Sharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am working on a crawler that uses PuppeteerSharp to get a web pages and analyze it.

But my problem is that I can not catch / find links that are inside a div, with a specific class and I have not been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

I have only been able to find documentation on how to capture / find all links on the page with this code syntax:

```
var jsSelectAllAnchors = @ "Array.from (document.querySelectorAll ('a')). map (a => a.href);";
var urls = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync <string []> (jsSelectAllAnchors);
```

Are there any who can help?
thanks in advance!

Comment: That code should work, can you share a little more of your use case?

Comment: yes the code to capture all links works but I have can not figure out how I can capture only those links which are inside a specific div. eg. if the html looks like this

<div class = "c1">
  <a href="/demo/"> demo </a>
</div>
<div class = "c2>
  <a href="/demo2/“> demo2 </a>
</div>

where I only want to capture the link that is in the div with class c1

Comment: `.c1 a` should do the trick